# help me find C wire on williamson boiler and where should I connect it

Tags: wiring, heating, thermostat-c-wire, boiler

I have Williamson boiler GWA 140,000 BTU. I have 2 zones in my house for heating. On one zone I want to install smart thermostat so, I need C wire. The old thermostat for this zone had 2 wires: red and white. The other zone's thermostat has 4 or 5 wires.

I am attaching the photos of boiler's wiring and one and off switch. Also can you tell if I am connecting c wire for only one zone then, should I do it at zone valve or at the thermostat?

*Image 1, shows the C wire I found and the manual says it should be to black wire to left on TSTAT wiring in third image*

[image: This is the C wire I found and the manual says it should be to black wire to left on TSTAT wiring in third image]

*Image 2,Just the boiler and all the wiring*

[image: Just the boiler and all the wiring]

*Image 3,TSTAT for red, green, white etc wires. BUT ON THIS BOILER IT DOESN'T FOLLOW THAT*

[image: TSTAT for red, green, white etc wires. BUT ON THIS BOILER IT DOESN'T FOLLOW THAT]

*Image 4,This is the on and off switch. The wires from the zones valves are connected here. The Transformer here has a blue wire. Does it mean the thermostat with 4 or 5 wire cable running has C wire?*

[image: This is the on and off switch. The wires from the zones valves are connected here. The Transformer here has a blue wire. Does it mean the thermostat with 4 or 5 wire cable running has C wire?]

*Image 5, This is low water cutoff and the C wire in Image 1 is connected to white wire which connects to this low water water cutoff sensor.*

[image: This is low water cutoff and the C wire in Image 1 is connected to white wire which connects to this low water water cutoff sensor.]

*Image 6, Another view of on and off switch. The black tape is where zone valve wiring is connected*

[image: Another view of on and off switch. The black tape is where zone valve wiring is connected.]

[image: This wiring diagram from manual]

[image: Another diagram]

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your boiler please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I added the photos of diagram from manual.